# python jsonschema use pattern on list items not working

Tags: python, jsonschema, python-jsonschema

I want to use json schema in order to validate something like this:

```json
{
  "function_mapper": {
    "critical": [
      "DataContentValidation.get_multiple_types_columns",
      "DataContentValidation.get_invalid_session_ids"
    ],
    "warning": [
      "DataContentValidation.get_columns_if_most_data_null",
      "FeatureContentValidation.detect_inconsistencies"
    ]
  }
}
```

And I want to use regex to check if the list content looks like this `Class.function` I've tried to change on of the functions to `'dataContentValidation.get_multiple_types_columns'`
and I came up with this schema but it didn't work:

```json
{
    "type": "object",
    "properties": {
        "function_mapper": {
            "type": "object",
            "properties": {
                "critical": {
                    "type": "array",
                    "uniqueItems": True,
                    "items":
                        {
                            "type": "string",
                            "pattern": r"[A-Z]\w+\.\w+"
                            # TODO add pattern that represent a class and function i.e: Class.function
                        }
                },
                "error": {
                    "type": "array",
                    "items": [
                        {
                            "type": "string",
                            "pattern": r"[A-Z]\w+\.\w+"
                            # TODO add pattern that represent a class and function i.e: Class.function
                        }
                    ]
                },
                "informative": {
                    "type": "array",
                    "items": [
                        {
                            "type": "string",
                            "pattern": r"[A-Z]\w+\.\w+"
                            # TODO add pattern that represent a class and function i.e: Class.function
                        }
                    ]
                }
            }
        },
        "days_gap": {"type": "integer", "minimum": 0},
        "timestamp_column": {"type": "string"},
        "missing_data_median_epsilon": {"type": "number", "minimum": 0, "maximum": 1},
        "group_by_time_unit": {"type": "string", "enum": ["d", "w", "m", "h", "T", "min", "s"]},
        "null_data_percentage": {"type": "number", "minimum": 0, "maximum": 1},
        "common_feature_threshold": {"type": "number", "minimum": 0, "maximum": 1},
        "columns_to_count": {"type": "array", "items": {"type": "string"}},
        "cluster_median_epsilon": {"type": "number", "minimum": 0, "maximum": 1},
        "app_session_id_column": {"type": "string"}
    }
}
```

I also tried replacing the contains with items but it still does not work.
What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Can you post the full schema?

Comment: I can but its super long i thought it would make it more difficult, Its also not the full json so if you think that would help I can also add it

Comment: This schema works for me if you put your test object under `{"function_mapper": <here>}`. And change `contains` to `items`. You could add `"additionalProperties": False` to the root object to avoid matching anything that is unspecified.

Comment: can you please specify what do you mean by "put your test object under {"function_mapper": <here>}"? Sorry I didn't really understand

Comment: You've already changed it in the post.

Comment: sorry but it still doesn't work that's how the json always looked my bad. I've added the new schema maybe something is still wrong in it

Comment: If the full schema is too long, consider providing a schema and instance that makes your problem minimal and reproduceable: https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example - You could use https://jsonschema.dev/ to easily confirm this.

Comment: @Relequestual I only added the needed part but I was asked to add it all

Comment: Ah, you're missing an open brace, but that can be fixed. In the event it's not possible to replicate the issue with fragments, as if often the case, the whole schema is sometimes helpful. I've not looked into the details here, yet.

Comment: Why do you have `r` in front of your regular expression strings?

Comment: Can you define "does not work"? What does or does not happen that you expect to happen?

Comment: @EmaIl I assumed you were using this as a python dict, is that not the case?

Comment: @Relequestual if the object is a python dict as I assumed, that's the python indicator for a regex string.

Comment: The patterns should be normal strings, and the validator will turn them into python regex strings internally.

Answer (score 1):

The `jsonschema.validate`, internally uses `re.search`, a regular expression package.

So, first check if you're getting desired result for re.search. Usually the re.search will give match for containing string so remember to put `$` in last of the pattern, so `re.search` will validate properly.

- example schema:

```py
schema = {
        "$schema": "http://json-schema.org/draft-04/schema#",
        "title": "",
        "type": "object",
        "properties": {
             "test_key": {
                "type": "string",
                "pattern": "^[Y|N]$"
            }
        }
}

json_to_validate = {"test_key":"Y"}

# to validate the schema
try:
        # created draft4validator because schema is written for draft4
        validator = jsonschema.Draft4Validator(schema)
        validator.validate(json_to_validate)
    except jsonschema.exceptions.ValidationError as err:
        log.debug("error reason: %s",err.message)
        # err.message will contain the explained error message
        raise ValueError(err.message)
    except Exception as err:
        raise
```

[validation error handling](https://python-jsonschema.readthedocs.io/en/latest/errors/)

Answer (score 0):

I see two issues with your schema that mean it is not valid JSON (Besides the comments).

For some reason you have an `r` before the regular expression open quote. That makes the JSON invalid.

You need to escape slashes in JSON. Pasting your schema into a JSON aware editor underlines this error.

Strings in JSON require some escaping...

```
Backspace is replaced with \b
Form feed is replaced with \f
Newline is replaced with \n
Carriage return is replaced with \r
Tab is replaced with \t
Double quote is replaced with \"
Backslash is replaced with \\
```

As per https://www.json.org

Without further hints as to what is wrong, I'm not sure I can help further.

Answer (score 0):

I assumed you were using what you've pasted as a python `dict`, but @Relequestual's comment made me realise that perhaps this was just a JSON question.

Here's a minimal example for what I did in Python, does that help?

```py
import jsonschema
from pprint import pprint

schema = {
    "type": "object",
    "properties": {
        "array_of_strings": {
            "type": "array",
            "items": {
                "type": "string",
                "pattern": r"\w\d",  # a letter and a number
            }
        }
    },
    "additionalProperties": False,
}

validator = jsonschema.Draft4Validator(schema)

def check(obj):
    pprint(obj)
    result = "VALID" if validator.is_valid(obj) else "INVALID"
    print(f"=> {result}")
```

Then with some test cases it passes and fails as expected:

```
>>> check({"array_of_strings": []})
{'array_of_strings': []}
=> VALID

>>> check({"array_of_strings": [""]})
{'array_of_strings': ['']}
=> INVALID

>>> check({"array_of_strings": ["A4"]})
{'array_of_strings': ['A4']}
=> VALID

>>> check({"array_of_strings": ["A4", "4A"]})
{'array_of_strings': ['A4', '4A']}
=> INVALID

>>> check({"array_of_strings": ["A4"], "other_key": "123"})
{'array_of_strings': ['A4'], 'other_key': '123'}
=> INVALID

>>> check({})
{}
=> VALID

>>> check({"other_key": []})
{'other_key': []}
=> INVALID

>>> check({"array_of_strings": {}})
{'array_of_strings': {}}
=> INVALID
```